# Node.js + Express: Upload a file without reloading page

Tags: ajax, node.js, file-upload, express

I am creating a chat application using Node.js, and would like to have a file upload feature. While I can get the file uploaded, the browser would always be redirected to another link or page refreshed, and this of course disrupts the chat.

**First** I tried using Express to do it:

index.html:

```
<form id="fileSendButton" action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

app.js:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    //some validation and rename file
    res.send();
    return false;
});
```

**Next** I tried using AJAX, but still couldnt do it, whenever the AJAX POST to the Node.js server, it would reload the page. My AJAX code anyway:

index.html:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/",  
    data: formdata,  
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
        document.getElementById("chatText").innerHTML = res; 
    } 
});  
return false;
```

**Third** I went to look at Uploadify, but didnt want to add Flash dependancy to my site, so I didnt implement it.

Anyone can help me please? I dont want a page reload when a file is uploaded.

Comment: I know this is a old post, but you can checkout https://www.npmjs.org/package/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a dynamically created hidden frame on the client side.

see [here](http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/18359176420/asynchronous-file-uploading-using-express-and-node-js) for a detailed howto with expressjs.

Comment: Oh my, thats a lot of code to get a file uploaded. I'll try it and see if it works. Thanks! Does anyone have other methods anyway?

Comment: Ok tried it and it works!
Need some minor changes though, like:
`var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)`
and
`app.use(express.bodyParser())`

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify now has a pure HTML5 play.

Comment: Thanks. I actually switched over to using Uploadify after 3 other plugins failed to work.